# How to structure multiple large AngularJS projects that have shared functionality between them?

Tags: angularjs, sass, gruntjs, frontend

I've been looking almost everywhere but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

We have multiple projects/apps that we'll develop using AngularJS and Sass. The problem is that we have shared/common UI components (services, controllers, filters, etc.) between these projects and we don't know how to structure all these.

All the projects will have their own modules with specific functionality, but technically we have to bring the common modules into each project (without copy-pasting them, obviously).

Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a standard or commonly accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go with the solution of a private bower repository in order to install all the common functionnality automatically.

Pros :

- force you to handle a versionning of your modules
- let bower handle install/update/dependancy/etc

Cons:

- you may have to rework your code to make standalone modules

More infos about private bower rep : http://www.toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/08/04/How-to-host-a-private-bower-registry/

And for the internal structure of an angular module, you can take a look at https://github.com/angular-app and https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp/tree/v0.3.1-release/src/app/home

Hope this helps